# Pillow verify() not finding corrupt jpgs

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, verify, corrupt

I followed a tutorial that had the following Python code to find corrupt jpg files. I have a corrupt jpg on which I've tested this and the script doesn't find the file. Is there anything I'm missing? Running Python 3.9.

*Edit: Sorry, I forgot to say. I did change the 'if endswith' to '.jpg' in my own script. This is just a copy pasta from the tutorial.*

```
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image



for filename in listdir('./'):

  if filename.endswith('.png'):`
      try:
          img = Image.open('./'+filename) # open the image file
          img.verify() # verify that it is, in fact an image
      except (IOError, SyntaxError) as e:
          print('Bad file:', filename) # print out the names of corrupt files
```

Comment: You are only checking png files.

Comment: change   if filename.endswith('.png'):`
to   if filename.endswith('.jpg'):`

Comment: Thanks, I did change that line to '.jpg' in my own script. I copied this code direct from the tutorial for this post. I've edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: Some more info. It did detect a corrupt 0 byte CR2 camera raw file. The jpg I've been using, isn't zero byte but half of it doesn't load properly.

Comment: Do you have an example of a corrupt image that you think `verify()` should flag?